# Displaying statistics collected by Moskito-central

Tags: java, web-applications

I wonder is it possible to show statistics, collected via *Moskito-central*, via *Moskito* inspector diagrams/charts?

In default *MoSKito-inspect* shows information only collected from the last client application startup, but I need to see some older data.

May be there is some import functionality (e.g. from json or csv) in *Moskito-inspect*, that I have not faced with?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately MoSKito Central only collects statistics but has no visual representation yet. The idea of MoSKito Central is to store the data in a tool of your choice, for example SQL-Database, Mongo (http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/connect-moskito-central-to-mongodb-database/), ElasticSearch or just FileSystem.

An evaluation tool is planned, but since MoSKito is an open source product and free to use, don't expect to get everything for free that a commercial product offers for 50.000 USD ;-)

regards
Leon